# How to enable findEssentialMat in opencv 2.4.9?

Tags: opencv, compilation

I'm being trying to use the new function findEssentialMat() in OpenCV 2.4.9 but when I try to compile my program it says that findEssentialMat is not defined. I include calib3d and I also link the proper library.

How should I compile OpenCV to enable the function?

This is my program:

> #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
>
> using namespace std;
>     using namespace cv;

```
Mat getEssential(const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints1,const vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints2,vector<DMatch>& matches){
vector<Point2f> p1, p2;
for (vector<DMatch>::const_iterator it= matches.begin();it!= matches.end(); ++it) {
    float x=keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.x;
    float y=keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.y;
    p1.push_back(Point2f(x,y));
    x=keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.x;
    y=keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.y;
    p2.push_back(Point2f(x,y));
}
Mat output;
Mat essen = findEssentialMat(p1,p2,focal,pp,CV_RANSAC,0.99,1,output);
vector<DMatch> inliers;
for(int i=0;i<output.rows;i++){
    int status=output.at<char>(i,0);
    if(status==1){
        inliers.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
}
matches=inliers;
return essen;
}

int main(){
  Ptr<FeatureDetector> fast = new FastFeatureDetector(10,true);
  Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = new PyramidAdaptedFeatureDetector(fast,3);
  FREAK freak(true,true,22.0f,0);
  BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING,true);

  vector<DMatch> matches;
  vector<KeyPoint> kp0,kp1;
  Mat d0, d1;
  Mat im0 = imread("/home/Chini/im0.png",0);
  Mat im1 = imread("/home/Chini/im1.png",0);
  detector->detect(im0,kp0,Mat());
  detector->detect(im1,kp0,Mat());
  freak.compute(im0,kp0,d0);
  freak.compute(im1,kp1,d1);
  matcher.match(d0,d1,matches);
  Mat e = getEssential(kp0,kp1,matches);
  }
```

When I try to compile it I received the following message:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘cv::Mat getEssential(const std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, const    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, std::vector<cv::DMatch>&)’:
example.cpp:18:62: error: ‘findEssentialMat’ is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no opencv 2.4.9?? Assuming you meant 2.4.0, you need to provide a lot more detail about the problem, like specific errors you are seeing, and a minimal code example would be great.

Comment: I downloaded OpenCV from github, I checked the version and it says 2.4.9. I update my question and add an example

Comment: Ah. I stick with official releases only, with 2.4.4 being the last right now, so I don't really know about any new functions like `findEssentialMat()`. My guess is that the new function either isn't in any of the headers included by `opencv2/opencv.hpp` in which case you need to hunt down the header than defines it, or maybe the function is in some experimental namespace and hasn't been moved into `cv::`. Since you are using a bleeding edge version of OpenCV, you will probably have to muck around in the source to find what you need.

Comment: I think this function exists only in version 3.0 which is currently in beta stadium.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do That

```
findEssentialMat()
```

is  a function implemented in the 3.x version

in accordance with the "How to Contribute OpenCV Guide" here: 
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute 
the 2.4.x opencv version has been feature frozen and are mainted just to give backward compatibility with legacy users, in their words:

"2.4 has been feature-frozen; as such, new functionality will not be accepted."

I strongly recommend that you install the 3.x version.

There is some good tutorials:
http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/#comment-125
http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/ (the last worked to me)